# EntrepriseLibrary version project

Tags: enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

Is there a way to add in pre/post compile config, of a project including EntrepriseLibrary, the version of of Entreprise he always need to search.

I try in the web.config of my web site.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <section name="enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  /> <!--requirePermission="true"  />-->
    <section name="securityConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Configuration.SecuritySettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  /> <!--requirePermission="true"/>-->
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

But not working.
Maybe its because its a shell project or its becaus I use CompositeWeb(V2).

```
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb 
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.EnterpriseLibrary
```

Maybe he search the wrong EnterpriseLibrary (version hardcoded)

So I ask if there a way to configure my shell project to force using EnterpriseLibrary 5?
Or maybe you have another way to correction my migration problem.

---

I got an old website in MVP .net2 VS2005. They ask me to keep it but transfert on VS2008 .net3.5. So I change somes libraries. Install EnterpriseLibrary 5. change every reference on my solution, using the old EnterpriseLibrary version. And now I got a problem.

One of my project, use for injection, need Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb and Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.EnterpriseLibrary. The old webSite use the version 1.1. But this version seem to ask to use EnterpriseLibrary 3.1. I need to change that. I cant find a version of compositeWeb who's using EnterpriseLibrary 5 (Maybe somebody else can?).
So, for correct my bug, some thread talk about using the web.config for changing the version of EnterpriseLibrary. I try but no good results. So I had the idea, why no use prebuild configuration to confige the compositeWeb to use the correction version of EnterpriseLibrary.

Comment: I have to be honest and say that it's hard to tell exactly what's being asked.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I edit the description. maybe this second part will help to understand my situation.